# How would adding more weight to grandpa voting of my initial authority at genesis affect finality?

Tags: grandpa, finality, genesis

Currently I am starting my node with one authority, and the genesis config for grandpa looks like this :

```rust
grandpa: GrandpaConfig { authorities: vec![] },
```

Would it be possible to assign some privileged accounts more weight in the Grandpa voting round after adding them to this `authorities` list like so?

```rust
grandpa: GrandpaConfig { authorities: intial_authorities.map(|x| (x.3.clone(), 10)) }
```

where assume `x.3` is the `GrandpaId` of `initial_authorities`. What kind of changes would this entail?

Edit: This doesn't work with the sessions pallet as it panics with an authority already initialized error. Anyway to bypass this behaviour and set custom weights to our grandpa authorities on genesis?

Comment: Is this still an open question, or should we close it? If it is an open question, is there anything further you can do to help clarify?

Comment: I think the question could've been rephrased better with an example. Say auth#1 has weight 20 and auth#2 and auth#3 have weight 5 respectively. Would it be possible for auth#1 to override the final chain against the votes of auth#2 and auth#3? I.E. if auth#2 and auth#3 vote on chain B and auth#1 on chain A, since auth#1 has weight 20, will chain A be the finalized chain?